# Get R.drawable ID's dynamically in android

Tags: android, resources, android-image

I have a folder with a few images, these images are added by user dynamically. So i need to get the R.drawable ID's of these images in android....  ???

Comment: The user is placing images in the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you saving these images too?  When images are being added dynamically at runtime usually you need to store them on the phones storage.  If you want the images to be stored in the external storage (SDCard) then you can use the following code to retrieve them and add them to your view (Which I assume your doing).  This code assumes the images are being stored to your devices SDCard, which is where they will be pulled from.

```
//Get root directory of storage directory, pass in the name of the Folder if they are      being stored farther down, i.e getExternalFilesDir("FolderName/FolderName2")

String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
// We can read and write the media


File dir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
    Bitmap bmap = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(dir,"image.jpg"));
        bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (bmap!=null) {
        ImageView view = new ImageView(this);
        view.setImageBitmap(bmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: But i need to get the R.drawable.ID of the images that are in the image view

Comment: Out of luck, anything being added dynamically will not be converted to an R.drawable.id after compiling.